# Use biber and bibtex in Winedt

Tags: bibtex, biber

Because of some journals sill require bibtex, I wanted to configure WinEdt to work with both bibtex and biber.

I installed the LaTeXify and now have the B+ button as shown here:

[image]

I am now trying to modify the commands for the "B+" button to work with Biber and leave the "B" button to work with bibtex.  I modified the MainMenu.ini file  as follows:

[image]

The "B+" button still remains grayed out.  Can you help me get the "B+" configured to work such that after I run PDFLaTeX for example, the "B+" becomes active, then exectute biber when I select it?  Thanks.

Comment: Is this somehow related to TeX or is it just about the configuration of the editor?

Comment: I would consider this both...it is TeX related and involves configuration of the WinEdt editor.  Thanks.

Comment: But it already works with `biber` if you have specified `backend=biber` on loading `biblatex`! Why do you want to change the default code?

Comment: @Bernard, some journals require bibtex instead of biber (for example the OSA Optica Journal).  I wanted to be able to have one button for bibtex, and then another for biber.  I tried your recommendation in the journal sty file but that does not work.  Thanks.

Comment: But you have a button for biber and another for bibtex, and specifying the backend decides which button is greyed and which is not. I don't understand where your problem is.

Comment: @Bernard, this was the original post:  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/303962/osa-optica-journal-to-work-with-biber.  Can you tell me then how to include your solution of `backend=biber` to work with this journal?  Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: I've checked: you have to use `natbib`, and not `biblatex` with  whatever backend.

Comment: @Bernard, besides manually having to change the bibtex path in WinEdt from biber.exe to bibtex.exe, is it possible to have a button for biber and another one for bibtex? Thanks.

Comment: @Joe: I don't understand: if you've installed the `latexify` package, you already have these buttons working ‘out of the box’ , as wrote @Ulrike Fischer. What do you want to do more? Each button is associated to a different path for the executable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't modify the winedt macros. There will work out of the box.

You can see in the macros a filter line:

```
REQ_FILTER=
```

This filter contains a pattern for the bcf-file and means that the button can only be used if a bcf-file exists which biber can process. Run a small document with biblatex and then your button will be active.

On my system after a clean up the buttons look like this:
[image]

And after the compilation: [image]. The bibtex button is now active too as its filter checks for the aux-file. The index button will be active if an idx exists.